# Why did my tinymce icon disappear suddenly vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, vuetify.js

This is my website screen

[image]

This is my tinymce code

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the following in the imports:

```
import 'tinymce/icons/default'
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE 5 contains an `icons` folder with two JavaScript files.  It would appear that you have not included that content in what you deployed to production.

I don't know how you package your application but you likely need to add something like this in the code that packages your application:

```
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "node_modules/tinymce/icons",
  "output": "/tinymce/icons/"
},
```

Comment: But i can't find where it should be placed

Comment: What path is leading to the 404 errors in the console?  I would place the files where TinyMCE is naturally looking for the content.  That is your simplest path forward.